# Execute Javascript in Visual force page of a managed package

Tags: visualforce, managed-package

I want to execute a javascript based on dom in a visual force page of a managed package.

Is that possible to do so?

Comment: Is it your managed package?  Or are you saying you want to supplement the VF page of a managed package you've installed in your org?

Comment: its not my managed package , its a package from a third party.

Comment: I think that means you're out of luck then.  Because you can't add JS to the VF page, the only way would be to have JS somewhere else on the page outside the VF that would act upon the VF page, which is something Salesforce have been actively campaigning against.

Answer (score 0):

I think that means you're out of luck then. Because you can't add JS to the VF page, the only way would be to have JS somewhere else on the page outside the VF that would act upon the VF page, which is something Salesforce have been actively campaigning against.